# Using multiple where clauses with laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having a lot of trouble converting the following SQL query to work with Laravel's query builder.

```
SELECT * FROM gifts 
JOIN giftcategory ON gifts.id = giftcategory.giftid
JOIN giftoccasions ON gifts.id = giftoccasions.giftid
JOIN giftrelationship ON gifts.id = giftrelationship.giftid

WHERE (gifts.gender = 'any' OR gifts.gender = 'male')
AND giftoccasions.occasionid = '2'
AND (giftcategory.categoryid = '0' OR giftcategory.categoryid = '1')
AND giftrelationship.relationshipid = '1'
```

This query works fine, but I can't get the same results when using Laravel's query builder. I have the following code so far. It is not working correctly at all. I'm thinking the issue could lie with the `orWhere` part because it seems to be returning results that don't match any of the other where clauses.

```
$giftQuery = DB::Table('gifts')
->Join('giftcategory', 'gifts.id', '=', 'giftcategory.giftid')
->Join('giftoccasions', 'gifts.id', '=', 'giftoccasions.giftid')
->where('gifts.gender', '=', "male")
->orwhere('gifts.gender', '=', "any")
->where('giftoccasions.occasionid', '=', "2")
->where('giftoccasions.relationshipid', '=', "1")
->Where('giftcategory.categoryid', '=', "0")
->orWhere('giftcategory.categoryid', '=', "1");
```

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to use [advanced where](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres) with parameter grouping:

```php
$giftQuery = DB::table('gifts')
    ->join('giftcategory', 'gifts.id', '=', 'giftcategory.giftid')
    ->join('giftoccasions', 'gifts.id', '=', 'giftoccasions.giftid')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('gifts.gender', '=', "male")
            ->orWhere('gifts.gender', '=', "any");
    })
    ->where('giftoccasions.occasionid', '=', "2")
    ->where('giftoccasions.relationshipid', '=', "1")
    ->where('giftcategory.categoryid', '=', "0")
    ->orWhere('giftcategory.categoryid', '=', "1");
```